# Linear and rotational movement

Tags: homework-and-exercises

In the system shown, when you put it in motion by pulling the weight $1$ downwards and then releasing it, does body 3 exhibit rotational motion as well and linear vertical motion. What is it's center of mass linear speed? Is it $\frac{1}{2}$ the speed of body 1?

[image]

Comment: Please note that homework-like questions should ask about a specific concept. You did not annotate the diagram sufficiently (what are the inner and outer radii of 2?) to answer this at any case - but you should really try to solve this yourself (draw the position of 3 after you pull on 1) and let us know what concept you are struggling with. We don't "do your homework for you".

Comment: Well, the reason I don't give radii, spring coefficients etc. is that I don't need someone to solve the problem for me. It's a problem from my exam earlier today. The problem asks us to find the differential equation of movement of body 1. I used the theorem that the derivative of the sum of the kinetic energies of all bodies with respect to time equals the power of the external forces. For the kinetic energy of body 3 I wasn't sure if I should include the $\frac {1}{2}I_c \omega ^2$ term. I think my question is conceptual: Does the disk 3 rotates as it moves up and down?

Comment: You specifically asked "is it half the speed of body 1" - which you cannot answer without knowing the ratio of radii. I will answer the conceptual question for you.

Comment: Oh, the outer radius of the spool is $R$ as is the radius of the disk. The inner radius is $r$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This diagram should tell you what you need to know - as the string is pulled, the pulley must rotate. Do you see it now?

[image]

Incidentally, the speed with which the second string (on 3) is pulled depends on the ratio $\frac{R}{r}$ - if you move the inner string (the one attached to 1) by $r$, the outer string will move by $R$. And that motion is then divided by two when it comes to the motion of the center of mass of 3.

I will leave you to figure out the rest.

Comment: Thanks, Floris, I was just impatient to find out if I did it right. And I kept imagining some "ideal" pulley with no friction between it and the rope and the pulley somehow slipping over it. It turns out I have at least one problem right. Yay! :)